# Forbidden (#403) - You are not allowed to perform this action?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This is backend `SiteController.php` access rules. When I going through this url `site.com/backend/web/site/login`. Its showing Forbidden (#403).

```
return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'addhotels'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Answer (score 6):

> An Error occurred while handling another error: exception
>   'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to
>   perform this action.' in
>   C:\wamp\www\k\kometonline\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:151

I was getting this error too and found this page through Google so hopefully this will help other people.

The error happens because you've added access control but you also need to explicitly allow the 'error' action in the site controller otherwise you'll get the same error. It's not immediately obvious because there isn't an action for it, also add the 'captcha' action, or you'll get the same problem with that.

In your site controller:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['register','login'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        //see captcha and error added here, this fixes the issue
                        'actions' => ['contact', 'about', 'terms', 'forgot', 'reset-password', 'captcha', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?', '@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `login` action from `AccessControl` list. or add `?` as roles for guest user in `AccessControl`.

For Example,

```
return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'], // " ? " for guest user
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'addhotels'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: am getting this error. An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' in C:\wamp\www\k\kometonline\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:151

Comment: I just added 'roles' => ['?']. When I remove login action from accesscontrol it shows 'Forbidden (#403)'

Comment: if you add `['?']` as roles. so do not remove `login` action from `actions` array..

Comment: so, remove `[
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'], // " ? " for guest user
                ],` part. then check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93370/discussion-between-gamitg-and-kartz).

Comment: The error here is caused by only allowing the error page to guests, you need to make it available to logged in users too else it won't work. 'roles' => ['?', '@'],

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to know how to allow non-logged in users to not receive Forbidden error in Backend. I am simply trying to renderPartial a test view with a single

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

and I receive the Forbidden error.

Comment: to not provide them a link to the backend, instread making sure they access only the sites front end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are already logged in as a user while trying to access the login page. This will throw a ForbiddenHttpException. Or you can customize this behavior by configuring the denyCallback property:

```
[
  'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [...],    
        'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
             //Add your error handler here
             throw new \Exception('You are not allowed to access this page');
         }
]
```

[See official guide/documentation here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)